# How to make window look symmetric after adding buttons to taskbar?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget

I have QMainWindow and I want to populate statusbar with buttons.

I achieve this by using the code:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QPushButton *leftBut = new QPushButton("left");
QPushButton *rightBut = new QPushButton("right");
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
layout->addWidget(leftBut, 1, 0);
layout->addWidget(rightBut, 1, 0);
statusBar()->addWidget(widget,1);
```

so, I have this: [MainWindow with buttons in statusbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo9Pq.png)

But you can see that right border of layout are far from window corner, not like on the left side.

What I want is to make window look symmetric (move right border right or make borders invisible or something else).

Comment: Try `widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);` for the top-level `widget`.

Comment: You might want to set the sizePolicy of your status bar or expand your HBoxlayout

Comment: I tried that and it seems to me that status bar is actively resisting to make it work like you want. You can try to resize the window and see. However, why status bar? If you want, I can publish an answer with these two buttons on the bottom horizontally centered just using layouts. I personally never use UI designer (you have that statusBar() function because of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was needed is this string after those code that I wrote in question:

```
statusBar()->setSizeGripEnabled(false);
```

In some reason statusbar contains "size grip" that is situated in bottom-right corner of statusbar and is enabled by default. That wast the thing that prevent widget to fill whole space.